# The only integer root of $\pi^{ix\pi} = 1$ is $x=0\:?$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory

Having the equation
\begin{align}
\pi^{ix\pi} = 1
\end{align}

I wanted to show that the only integer solution is $x=0$. Taking the $\ln$ on both sides gives
\begin{align}
& i\pi x\ln\pi = 2i\pi n\\
& x = \frac{2n}{\ln \pi}
\end{align}

where $n$ is an integer. When $n=0$, the root is $0$. If $n\neq0$, we can assume that $x=2n/\ln\pi$ is a not null integer and find a contradiction. Below, $m$ is integer
\begin{align}
\frac{2n}{\ln\pi} = m \implies \ln \pi = \frac{2n}{m}.
\end{align}

Since the irrationality of $\ln \pi$ is unknow, this proves nothing.

How to show that $2n/\ln\pi$ is not integer $?$

Comment: Why is $\ln 1 = 2 i \pi n$?

Comment: @Sam By Euler $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\Rightarrow e^{2\pi in}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{2n}{\ln \pi}$ was integer that would mean that $\ln \pi$ is a rational number. So you are basically asking how to prove that $\ln \pi$ is rational.

It turns out that we do not actually know if $\ln \pi$ is rational or not (although it is important to note that it follows from Schanuel's conjecture which is believed to be true - but we haven't proved it yet!). It is an open problem. You will find some useful references and insights [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253070/is-it-possible-to-know-if-log-pi-is-irrational-or-not-since-the-log-func).